# Coldfusion ListToArray and using "==" as a delimiter

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

The code:

```
<cfset LOCAL.temp = 'something==a descript >= ive value' />
<cfdump var="#ListToArray(LOCAL.temp, '==')#" />
```

What I expect is an array with two indices what I get is an array with three indices, CF is also splitting at the single equals sign.

Is anyone else experiencing this behavior or can explain what is going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. As described in the docs, [ListToArray](http://cfdocs.org/listtoarray) uses single-character delimiters (by default).

One solution is to use split:

```
Temp.split('==')
```

*(This is making use of the underlying Java [string.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method, which splits a string at every match of a specified regex, and works on all Java-based CFML engines, though produces a Java String Array - which can't be directly manipulated with CF's ArrayAppend and related functions, unless it is first [converted](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/760-Converting-A-Java-Array-To-A-ColdFusion-Array.htm). ).*

Since you're on CF9, you can also use the new multi-char delimiter flag, by setting the fourth argument to true:

```
ListToArray(Temp,'==',false,true)
```

Comment: ... and that's what I get for not reading the documentation, thanks!

Comment: FYI, one nuance of `split()` is it returns an immutable array. Just something to watch out for on older versions.

Comment: Leigh, can you clarify when that applies - string.split on CF9 produces a modifiable array, [Ben Nadel's blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/760-Converting-A-Java-Array-To-A-ColdFusion-Array.htm) suggests it's CF7 problem, so is CF8 affected?

Comment: Peter - I get the same result under CF10. AFAIK it applies to all versions. `String.split()` returns a java array ie `String[]` rather than a CF's version which is a `java.util.List`. Since unlike lists, java arrays are immutable, it does not work with functions like `arrayAppend`. (Edit) You need to do a little extra like in Ben's post.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood - modifying the values work, modifying the array itself is the problem.